# FileNotFoundException when accessing a file from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I get a FileNotFoundException when trying to access a file from an object contained in a servlet.  The file is in the WEB-INF/classes directory.  The war file has been deployed to JBOSS 6.3.

I have tried various ways to access the file:

1)  InputStream path = new FileInputStream();

2)  ClassLoader cLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream path = cLoader.getResourceAsStream();

Do I need to list the filename or class names in any of the JBOSS configuration files?

When I run 1) above, I get the FileNotFoundException.

When I run 2) above, I get a ClassNotFoundException.  From the servlet I can find the class, but not from the class itself.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score -1):

I would start by checking where your default path is pointing to using the ServletContext object.

```
String realContextPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
System.out.println("REAL CONTEXT PATH: " + realContextPath);
```

Then make sure your path that your constructing is actually the correct path, my setup already includes the /WEB-INF directory.

```
File file = new File(realContextPath+"/js/login.js");
```

Comment: @BalusC It's bad advice to see if whatever path he is using is valid?